# Adobe Flash game, hitting with the mouse

Tags: flash, button, mouse

I want my mouse to click on something that is moving, and when it clicks, I want the game to go to another frame. My problem is that when I hit it, it just does nothing. So my code must certainly be wrong.

I've tried this code:

```
function pisando( e:Event ):void{
    if(pie.hitTestObject(ant.antmove)){
        ant.antmove.gotoAndPlay(8);
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
botDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotationDown);
function rotationDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
    canon.prevFrame();
}
```

None of them work... Any ideas?

It must be really simple, but when one just doesn't know it becomes hard.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code, right now what you're doing is changing the **MovieClip's** (ant.antmove) current frame. You mentioned you want the game to change frames, this is accomplished changing the main timeline's frame (assuming you're coding directly into the timeline). Therefore, instead of using `ant.antmove.gotoAndPlay(8);` try using `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(8);`

The code would be like this:

```
function pisando( e:Event ):void{
    if(pie.hitTestObject(ant.antmove)) {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(8);
    }
}
```

This post can help you understand a little more about the root object in Flash: http://www.thomastalkstech.com/blog1.php/casting-root-actionscript-3-0-finding-yo